# Packages failing to load after R update

Tags: r, package

In RStudio
This .Rprofile line:-
library(tidyverse) 
gives error below

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’

Comment: Install the vctrs package

Comment: Thanks Phil - I had found it, although I was being told it did not exist when I tried to install,  rRe loaded R from scratch and all OK.